# unity3d spaceshooter movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hi** Folks, i have some problems with the rotation of my spaceship. If i press the left arrow, and switch to the right arrow the rotation is switching instantly. How can i Smooth it up?

**Video:**
https://sendvid.com/fek9izy3

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.velocity = movement * speed;

    rb.position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
    );

    rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 180, rb.velocity.x * -tilt);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want realistic physics, don't directly modify a rigidbody's position or rotation. Instead use [Rigidbody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) for linear movement, and [Rigidbody.AddTorque](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) for rotation.

To smoothly rotate the ship, you would do something like this:

```
float speed = 10f;

rb.AddTorque( new Vector3(0f, 0f, moveHorizontal * speed) );
```